# Loading a list into seperate Entry widgets

Tags: python, string, list, tkinter

I have a list and I want each string in the list to be displayed into a different Entry widget. I start by getting the length as it may vary and then use the `for I in range(l)` command to make the next part loop for each string in the list. The `a=0` loads each different string when it is their time to be loaded. I think the problem is that the `textvariable=self.example_var` command it causing all of the loaded widgets to appear empty except the last one that 
has the correct string in it.

Basically, all the correct amount of entry widgets load, but the strings are not in them except the last one.

```
l=len(selectedetails)

a=0
for i in range(l):
    self.example_var = StringVar()
    self.example_var.set(selectedetails[a])
    self.example_txt = Entry(top1,textvariable=self.example_var)
    print(selectedetails[a])
    self.example_txt.pack()

    a=a+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend *not* using a `StringVar`. It serves no real purpose for how you're using the entry widget, and it adds an extra object that needs to be tracked.

I also recommend *not* calculating the length and iterating over the index. The more pythonic way is to directly iterate over the items in the list:

```
entries = []
for item in selectiondetails:
    entry = Entry(top1)
    entry.insert(0, item)
    entry.pack()
    entries.append(entry)
```

Later, when you need to get the values out, you can iterate over `entries`:

```
for entry in entries:
    print(entry.get())
```